# increment operator ( increment decreases the value not sure why tried with gcc as well mingw and online compilers)

Tags: c

While creating reverse polish notation calculator. i came across this . Unable to understand why such values were being assigned while debugging , i isolated the problem statements into another simpler program which is as follows and it gives the same output which i am having difficulty understanding . Can anyone explain why is it different from my expected output (or simply how this output was reached). Your help would be highly appreciated!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int top_stack =  1;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d" , top_stack + 1 , top_stack , top_stack++) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output  :- 3  2  1

I was expecting the output to be 2 1 1

Comment: Hint: What order are the arguments evaluated in? What does the C standard require?

Comment: Evaluation order of the arguments are undefined but afaik traditionally it's from right to left. So you shouldn't rely on anything about that ordering.

Comment: @Aakarsh MJ The function has undefined behavior. There is no sequence point in the evaluation of function arguments.

Comment: Arguments are evaluated from right to left according to C standards hence the output (FOR SELF REFERRENCE).